# Ajax fails but the call succeeds when I access the URL directly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, firebug

I'm making the following AJAX call from firebug:

```
var rootUrl = 'http://172.24.105.22:8080/geoserver/Chennai_Sub/ows';

var defaultParameters = {
    service: 'WFS',
    version: '1.0.0',
    request: 'GetFeature',
    typeName: 'Chennai_Sub:Link',
    maxFeatures: 200,
    outputFormat: 'application/json',
    format_options: 'callback: getJson'

};

$.ajax({
    url: rootUrl,
    data: defaultParameters,
    success: function () {
        console.log("victory");
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(textStatus);
    }
});
```

The AJAX call fails. This is some part of the response object I get:

```
readyState  4
status  404
statusText  "error"
```

But when I actually try to open the URL (`http://172.24.105.22:8080/geoserver/Chennai_Sub/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=Chennai_Sub%3ALink&maxFeatures=200&outputFormat=application%2Fjson&format_options=callback%3A+getJson`) in my browser, I get a clean JSON response. Any idea on what I'm doing wrong ?

(Also, I try the firebug session in this URL: `http://172.24.105.22:3000/layer`. So I don't think so this is the CORS problem.)

Comment: Not sure if it would change anything but have you tried adding a `method` property?

Comment: @War10ck What do you mean by `method` ? If you asking about the `get` type, then yes. But that didn't work.

Comment: Yes that's what I was referring to. `method: "GET"` or `method: "POST"`, in the jQuery `$.ajax({ ... });` object...

Comment: could you provide url from browser console that $.ajax is making?

Comment: @vergilius `http://172.24.105.22:3000/layer`

Comment: well, there are different ports 3000/8080

Comment: @vergilius Is that an issue ? Will it cause any trouble in `AJAX` ?

Comment: @Sibi As far as I know AJAX requests are allowed only in the same domain, protocol and port due to Same Origin Policy. But I might be wrong, you are receiving 404 ;/

Comment: @vergilius Yeah, that makes sense now. But then why isn't I'm getting `Forbidden` error ?

Comment: @vergilius Can you post that comment as an answer, I will accept it. Indeed i'm facing with the same origin policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That might not be right solution, but I believe different ports might cause such problem.

From comment above

> AJAX requests are allowed only in the same domain, protocol and
>   port due to Same Origin Policy.

What Wikipedia says about that:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Comment: This is the right solution. Even different ports cause problem. I tested in the same port and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't access any of the URLs provided, maybe your server can't access them too, although your local computer might be able to? Make sure target URL is accessible from your website. Also, if you're calling the AJAX request from the same server as the target one, I would suggest using relative URL instead of absolute one.

Another option, if the above doesn't work, is to use the [$.get](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) request of jQuery instead of [$.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

```
$.get('http://172.24.105.22:8080/geoserver/Chennai_Sub/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=Chennai_Sub%3ALink&maxFeatures=200&outputFormat=application%2Fjson&format_options=callback%3A+getJson', function(response) {
console.log(response);
})
```

Or

```
$.get('http://172.24.105.22:8080/geoserver/Chennai_Sub/ows', defaultParameters, function(response) {
console.log(response);
})
```

Comment: It's on local LAN, so ofcourse you will not be able to access it.

Comment: Even better option would be to post data, if the API accepts POST requests. The URL is pretty long and some web servers might be restricting maximum length of URLs for security reasons.

Comment: Any way to make it live so we can assist you better?

Answer (score 0):

Well, for a start thats a 404 which means that the the client was able to communicate with the server, but the server could not find what was requested. So just make sure that theres actually a route to for that rootURL.