# Debug Ajax Issue in Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, server, webforms, asp.net-ajax

To begin with, My AJAX is working fine in my local solution but once deployed in non production servers AJAX is not working. It does not even giving any error but only request pending status in network tab in Dev Tools with the below message:

[image]

[image]

I already tried everything on my local to work ajax in servers including code change in both api call and controller. Routes are also good. The script reference is present. Calling URL in ajax is good. JSON.Stringify is also done in my ajax.

I can't share the exact code since it is on my office laptop and I am just using my personal laptop.
Please help I am stuck for 2 months now. Don't know what to do.
#ajax, #aspnet #webforms #c#

Comment: It looks similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22508920/ajax-fails-but-the-call-succeeds-when-i-access-the-url-directly/22538288

Comment: Server operating system? Any javascript error in browser console?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.